# Differentiate between data coming in my Service bus Queue

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Below is an Azure function which pushes data in My Service Bus from my cosmos db. this is already written code and here they check the different metadata before returning the Json to service bus. Now I have to write another function where I am pulling these data from Service bus and processing it further based on data coming from above function or from other sources as the requirement is changing and I might get data in Service Bus from other sources. I would like to know how can I distinguish these data to identify which comes from where.

```
[FunctionName( "Push Data to Service Bus" )]
        [return: ServiceBus( "topicname", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection" )]
        public static string Notify(
            [CosmosDBTrigger(
                databaseName: "test",
                collectionName: "testcontay",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
                LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
                CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]
                IReadOnlyList<Document> documents,
            ILogger log )
        {
            if( documents == null || documents.Count == 0 )
            {
                log.LogWarning( "No documents received" );
                return null;
            }


            var triggerDocs =
                (from d in documents
                 let trigger = d.GetPropertyValue<bool?>( "Trigger" )
                 where !trigger.HasValue || trigger == true
                 select new
                 {
                     Id = d.GetPropertyValue<string>( "id" ),
                     Project = d.GetPropertyValue<string>( "Project" ),
                     ProjectId = d.GetPropertyValue<string>( "ProjectId" ),
                     Tags = d.GetPropertyValue<string[]>( "Tags" ),
                     Properties = d.GetPropertyValue<Dictionary<string, object>>( "Properties" ),
                     Categories = d.GetPropertyValue<string[]>( "Categories" ),
                     Trigger = d.GetPropertyValue<bool?>( "Trigger" ),
                     Received = DateTime.UtcNow
                 }).ToList();


            log.LogInformation( $"Documents triggered: {triggerDocs.Count}" );

            if( triggerDocs.Count() == 0 )
                return string.Empty;

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize( triggerDocs, triggerDocs.GetType() );
            return json;
        }


[FunctionName( "GettingDataFromServiceBus" )]
        public async void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topicname", "subscriptionname",
            Connection = "AzureServiceBusString")] 
            string SbMsg, ExecutionContext context,
            ILogger log)
        {
           
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SbMsg))
                {
                    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {SbMsg}");
}
}
```

Comment: You are already using topic and subscription. So you have apply the filter on subscription and use it in your new Azure function

Comment: but then that will call for creating two subscription. in my requirement all json Data is coming in one subscription. Is there anyway I do a filtering over sbMsg that is checking if sbMsg has the same properties as was pushed from CosmosDb trigger

Comment: Check this - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4439. Which states that it is not supported currently. You can either follow up same github isuse or create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
    //Such as this is your message.
    string str = "{\"projectID\":\"111\"}";
    try
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(str);
        if (obj["projectID"] != null)
        {
            //Message have projectID, so it is from xxx.
        }
        else
        {
            //Message don't have projectID, so it is from xxx.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { 
        //Message format is not json, so it is comes from xxx.
    }
```

**Original Answer:**

You can use custom properties to achieve your requirement. Add ApplicationProperties to message, then post it to azure service bus queue.

Have a look at this(Based on .Net):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage?view=azure-dotnet#properties

**C# sample:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://bowman1012.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=X/NHgQ4AQxul6YlMsUofD+JNE20Tovnzx3g2gDt8qyY=";
            string queueName = "queuename";
            string source = "function";
            await SendMessageAsync(connectionString, queueName, source);
        }
        static async Task SendMessageAsync(string connectionString,string queueName,string source)
        {
            // create a Service Bus client 
            await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString))
            {
                // create a sender for the queue 
                ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

                // create a message that we can send
                ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage("Hello world!");
                message.ApplicationProperties.Add("message_source",source);

                // send the message
                await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
                Console.WriteLine($"Sent a single message to the queue: {queueName}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont think it has to do anything with Service Bus.. I have an array of data, and I need to do filtering on that data, before I process further

Comment: @AnkitKumar What I mean is to use the custom attributes of the message to record the source of information (using key-value), and then you can filter based on this.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by that? Are you asking me to have another attribute in my data and then use that for filtering?

Comment: @AnkitKumar Yes, use the custom attribute. I don't think there has a built-in method to find the source of the message.

Comment: well thats not what i can do.. i cant change the data

Comment: @AnkitKumar I updated a piece of code based on C#. The source of the message needs to be specified in advance by design, because it does not contain source information. If the data itself does not contain source information, then I think you should not be able to obtain the source information.

Comment: I see your point here, but thats something we cant do, We cant change the code  and data will be coming from different sources. But what I am assuming here is to figure out if my data coming in has the Values as ID, project, projectId etc to recognize that it comes from my DB and rest all data without those properties are from other DB.

Comment: @AnkitKumar Your data only have [these things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNmTo.png) by default.

Comment: also the above properties in my array. and few items in my array will not have those properties.. so i just need a way to distinguish between them

Comment: @AnkitKumar I notice you return the json, Seems your projectId etc is in the body?

Comment: thats correct.. and other sources will not have these attributes in their body

Comment: @AnkitKumar If this is the case, I think you can set up logic to check the content of the information in the second function based on the differences between the information from different sources (provided that there are differences in the message content).

Comment: thats correct, thats what I am trying to do, check if each item in my array have these properties or not

Comment: @AnkitKumar Sorry, I just had something to do, so I did not reply. I updated the answer. It is simple logic (not sure about the information structure of your various sources, just made an assumption). If there are any points you want to raise, please leave a message here. I'm going to sleep.  Good night:)